# ASP.Net MVC3 Razor Href Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

For some reason this line of code.

```
<a href="/API/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.site_url)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.api_name)</a>
```

is throwing the error.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation
```

Web search has been no help I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with the code.

The page is not strongly typed.

Comment: There is no point in calling `DisplayFor` there.

Comment: What is the type of `item`, and why aren't you using `modelItem` in your lambdas? Also, why are you using `DisplayFor` when you could simply directly output the values?

Comment: I made the page strongly typed which fixed the issue thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error states, you can't use dynamic models with type-safe editor helpers.

You should use typed models instead. (using `@model SomeType`)

Answer (score 0):

Is your view strongly typed?  If not, you need to have a strongly typed view, as lambdas don't support dynamic members.

Just add this to the top of your view:

```
@model YourModel
```